# How to add sleep and wait logic in javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas, settimeout, sleep

We are working on visualization of sorting algorithms, required to add sleep and wait logic to help visualize the selected element and the element to which it is compared. After searching li'l bit, we found a code "function sleep(milliseconds){...}" which should work as desired but has failed so far.

In function insertionSort(){...}, the current element is depicted with color red and the element to which it is compared with is depicted with color blue, once the current element is swapped with the other the color of the element is again changed to white from blue (working correctly, verified using debugger), However during execution, these color transformations were not visible (only the element in red is displayed after each iteration)

```js
var element = function(value, color)
{
  this.value = value;
  this.color = color;
};

var x = [];
x[0] = new element(2, "white");
x[1] = new element(1, "white");
x[2] = new element(5, "white");
x[3] = new element(4, "white");
x[4] = new element(3, "white");
x[5] = new element(7, "white");
x[6] = new element(6, "white");
x[7] = new element(8, "white");
x[8] = new element(10, "white");
x[9] = new element(9, "white"); 


var i = 1;
var context;
var delayTime = 1000;

function myFunction()
{
   var bar = document.getElementById("bar");
   width = bar.width;
  height = bar.height;
   context = bar.getContext("2d");
  window.setInterval(insertionSort, 3000);
}

function insertionSort()
{
    if(i>=0 && i<x.length)
    {
       
  var j = i;
  x[j].color = "red";
  drawGraph(j);
  while(j>0 && x[j-1].value > x[j].value)
  {
    
     x[j-1].color = "blue";
    x[j].color = "red";
   drawGraph();
   //need to add delay here
   sleep(delayTime);
   //swap
   var temp = x[j];
   x[j] = x[j-1];
   x[j-1] =  temp;
   drawGraph();
   // and here...
   sleep(delayTime);
   
   x[j].color = "white";
   drawGraph();
   
   j = j-1;
  }
  x[j].color = "white";
  i++;
   }
   else if(i>=x.length)
   {
      for(k=0;k<x.length;k++)
      {
      x[k].color = "white";
     }
       drawGraph();
       i=-1;
   }
}

function sleep(milliseconds) 
{
   var start = new Date().getTime();
  for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) 
  {
     if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds)
     {
        break;
     }
   }
}

function drawGraph()
{ 
 context.StrokeStyle = "black";
 context.clearRect ( 0 , 0 , width, height);
    for(k=0;k<x.length;k++)
    {    
  context.fillStyle = x[k].color;
  //x and y coordinate of top left corner of rectangle
     context.strokeRect(400+k*20, 18, 20, x[k].value*10);
     context.fillRect(400+k*20, 18, 20, x[k].value*10);
       
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../p5.js"></script>
  <!-- uncomment lines below to include extra p5 libraries -->
 <!--<script language="javascript" src="../addons/p5.dom.js"></script>-->
  <!--<script language="javascript" src="../addons/p5.sound.js"></script>-->
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="sketch.js"></script>
  <!-- this line removes any default padding and style. you might only need one of these values set. -->
  <style> body {padding: 0; margin: 0;} </style>
</head>

<body>
  
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
  <canvas id="bar" width="1000" height="400" style="border:2px"></canvas>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain *exactly* how this function is failing. Thanks for improving the question's reference value and making it more answerable!

Answer (score 2):

The approach to used in that implementation of sleep() would be terrible in any programming language, because it consumes a lot of CPU while waiting.  In JavaScript, however, it's especially bad, because a JavaScript program is required to relinquish control frequently; it is not permitted to keep computing for an extended period of time. In Chrome browser, for example, Chrome will consider the program to be unresponsive, and will suggest to the user that they kill it.

But even if that weren't the case, it won't produce the desired effect, which I assume is that some animation happens on the screen, with some delay from one step to the next.  The way JavaScript works in the browser, is that any changes you make to the page get rendered when your program relinquishes control; nothing updated on-screen while any JavaScript code is running.  If you call a sleep function like that one, you are not relinquishing control, you are running JavaScript the whole time, and therefore the browser will not update the screen during that time. It will only update when your entire insertionSort method returns, and the browser has that 3000ms time window (from your setInterval) to take care of its own stuff (rendering).

Unfortunately, you will have to find a way to split up that algorithm, so that each step that you want to be distinctly visible to the user happens in its own timed callback.

It will probably be something along the lines of:

```
function stepOne() {
  do the first bit; 
  setTimeout(secondStep, delay)
}

secondStep() {
  do some more stuff;
  setTimeout(thirdStep, delay)
}
```

and so on.  The way you control the speed of the animation is with the delay parameter from one step to the next.

It's going to be tricky, especially because you aren't just trying to animate Insertion Sort, but various algorithms. So then, do you break them all up as in: insertionSortStepOne/Two/Three, shellSortStepOne/Two/Three? that would be quite ugly.

Depending on how ambitious you are, and how much you want to get out of this assignment, you might explore this feature of ES6 (a newer version of JavaScript)

[function*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*)

What this lets you do is let your function, with all its nested loops, remain structured pretty much as it is, but you insert points where it relinquishes control.  Later, it is called back to continue from the point where it left off. You would use setTimeout or setInterval to do that.  I've not experimented with this myself, but it seems super-cool.